# python-igraph: find intersecting edges in a graph based on vertices location

Tags: python, igraph, shapely

I am trying to detect the graph edges that intersects based on some constraints. My code is as follows:

```
#getCellPinPts returns coordinates of the vertex
# I am using igraph and shapely packages 
linestrings = [LineString((getCellPinPts(G.es[edge]["startCell"],cellMid[G.es[edge]["nameIdx"]],
                                G.es[edge]["pin"], G["stepSize"]), 
                                getCellPinPts(G.es[edge]["endCell"],cellMid[G.es[edge]["endNameIdx"]],
                                G.es[edge]["endPin"], G["stepSize"]))) for edge in range(len(G.es))]
intersect = [ 1 for idx1,x in enumerate(linestrings) for idx2,y in enumerate(linestrings) if idx1<idx2 
     and x.intersects(y) 
     and not(G.es[idx1]["family"] == G.es[idx2]["family"]) 
    ]
totalIntersections = np.sum(intersect)
```

The problems is due to the nested loop it takes a lot of time to calculate the intersections. Is there anyway to make the intersect code faster?